# Ubuntu-sdk Kits, mkspec and dbus errors

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk, python3, dbus

This is a double part issue :

When I launch the ubuntu sdk I get the following message in the General Messages pane:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/share/qtcreator/ubuntu/scripts/qtc_chroot_cmake2", line 24, in <module>
import dbus
ImportError: No module named 'dbus'
```

In the kit creation I have the following error for my "UbuntuSDK for armhf (GCC ubuntu-sdk-14.10-utopic)" kit (and for all other kit expect for the Desktop one) :

```
Mkspec not found for Qt version
```

This behavior was not present when I installed the sdk. I was able to use the sdk to compile for my ubuntu phone.
I think things have changed after I installed python 3.4.3 (but I am not really sure).

Thanks in advance for any help.